# How to install GPflow on PyCharm if I have anaconda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, gpflow

I tried download the package and `python setup.py develop`. However this directly installs GPflow under anaconda. Plus this isn't really working anaconda and gives error

```
/Users/Chu/anaconda/bin/python /Users/Chu/Documents/dssg/dssg.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chu/Documents/dssg/dssg.py", line 4, in <module>
    import GPflow
  File "/Users/Chu/Documents/GPflow-master/GPflow/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import (likelihoods, kernels, ekernels, param, model, gpmc, sgpmc, priors, gpr, svgp, vgp, sgpr, gplvm, tf_wraps,
  File "/Users/Chu/Documents/GPflow-master/GPflow/likelihoods.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import densities, transforms
  File "/Users/Chu/Documents/GPflow-master/GPflow/transforms.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import tf_wraps as tfw
  File "/Users/Chu/Documents/GPflow-master/GPflow/tf_wraps.py", line 36, in <module>
    _custom_op_module = tf.load_op_library(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'tfops', 'matpackops.so'))
  File "/Users/Chu/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 64, in load_op_library
    None, None, error_msg, error_code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: dlopen(/Users/Chu/Documents/GPflow-master/GPflow/tfops/matpackops.so, 6): image not found
```

So I think I should try install it under library? Here are some other captures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue even if when I try to install it outside Pycharm. I looked into the reported issue in Github, and the problem was solved for someone else when he built TensorFlow from scratch uisng gcc5

I dont think you can just simply install GPflow on pycharm. Do it outside and then you can use it. Here is the link where it is reported to be solved:

https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/192